# Valgrind Block are Lost

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to understand why the follow code is wrong using valgrind. The problem apparently is in the function destroy_poli, I say this because when I comment this part of the main function

```
poli ** p = (poli **) malloc( sizeof( poli *) * npols );
for(k=0;k<npols;k++) {
    p[k] = new_poli( nvars, w  );
}
for(k=0;k<npols;k++)
    destroy_poli(p[k]);
free(p);
```

I get 0 errors with valgrind. Please Could you help to undersantd where my error is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bits.h"
#include "parsemap.h"
#include "galois.h"
#define ANF 1
#define pos(i,j) (((1+i)*i)/2 + j)
int *table_red;
typedef struct _mono {
    int w;
    char ** v;
} mono;

typedef struct _poli {
    int nvars;
    mono ** p;
} poli;

void destroy_mono(mono * m){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<2*(m->w);i++)
        free(m->v[i]);
    free(m->v);

}

void destroy_poli(poli * p){
    int nvars = p->nvars;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<((nvars+1)*nvars)/2;i++)
        destroy_mono(p->p[i]);
    free(p->p);
}

mono * new_mono( int w, int idx ) {
    int i;
    mono * r = (mono *) malloc( sizeof(mono) );
    r->w = w;
    r->v = (char **) malloc( sizeof(char *)*( 2*w ) );
    for( i = 0; i < 2*w; i++ ) {
        r->v[i] = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char )*( 4096 ) );
        r->v[i][0] = 0;
    }

    return r;
}

poli * new_poli( int nvars, int w  ) {
    poli * p = (poli *) malloc( sizeof(poli) );
    p->nvars = nvars;

    int i,j;
    nvars++;
    p->p = (mono **) malloc( sizeof( mono * ) * ((nvars+1)*nvars)/2);
    nvars--;
    for(i=0; i < nvars; i++ )
    for(j=0; j <=i; j++ )       
            p->p[pos(i,j)] = new_mono( w, i );
    }
   return p;
}

void create_table( int w ) {
    table_red = (int *) malloc( sizeof( int ) * 2 * w );
    int i, j, a, b;
    for(i=0;i<2*w;i++) {
        table_red[i] = mod( (1 << i), w );
    }
}
int ** read_input( int * npols, int * nvars, int * w, int ** enc ) {
    int i, j;
    *npols = 1;
    *nvars = 1;
    int nv = *nvars + 1;
    int np = *npols;
    *enc = (int *) malloc( sizeof( int) * np );
    for(i=0; i < np; i++ ) {
        (*enc)[i] = 0;
    }
    int ** coefs = (int **) malloc( sizeof( int *) * np );
    for(i=0; i < np; i++ ) {
        coefs[i] =  (int *) malloc( sizeof( int) * ((nv+1)*nv)/2 );
        for(j=0; j < ((nv+1)*nv)/2; j++)
        coefs[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return coefs;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int nvars;
    int npols;
    int i;
    int w = 2, *enc;

    int ** coefs = read_input( &npols, &nvars, &w, &enc );
    int k, j;
    create_table( w );
    npols = 1;
    poli ** p = (poli **) malloc( sizeof( poli *) * npols );
    for(k=0;k<npols;k++) {
        p[k] = new_poli( nvars, w  );
    }
    for(k=0;k<npols;k++)
        destroy_poli(p[k]);
    free(p);

    for(i=0; i < npols; i++ )
        free(coefs[i]);
    free(coefs);

    free(enc);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
==24066== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==24066==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24066==    by 0x400CE8: new_poli (in /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/mq2sat/mq2sat/mq2sat)
==24066==    by 0x400FD7: main (in /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/mq2sat/mq2sat/mq2sat)
==24066== 
==24066== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==24066==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24066==    by 0x400C46: new_mono (in /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/mq2sat/mq2sat/mq2sat)
==24066==    by 0x400D70: new_poli (in /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/mq2sat/mq2sat/mq2sat)
==24066==    by 0x400FD7: main (in /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/mq2sat/mq2sat/mq2sat)
==24066==
```

Comment: It gives you the line numbers where those blocks were allocated (and the function that called that function, and so on). So look at which blocks get allocated on those lines, then look at where they're *supposed* to be freed (and apparently not freed) and there's your problem.

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) TL;DR Provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's too hard to see where is the problem (*you've used a lot of `malloc()`s, you didn't check for `malloc()` errors even once, and you used `malloc()` where sometimes it was not needed. You also used `malloc()` for a global variable, that's a bad idea. The global variable itself is a bad idea*), but the most important thing is to compile with `-g` to let valgrind display the line numbers. Also, your code mixes declarations with statements a lot (*it's a mess too*), so it's hard to see the context/scope for a given variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `free(p)` in `destroy_poli()` and `free(m)` in `destroy_mono()`. I was able to determine that by compiling with `-g` and using *valgrind* to check the line nunmber where the leaked pointer was allocated tracking it led me to find the problem. Another thing I did was write the code in a way that it can be debugged and maintained, please check this and tell me whether or not it's worth the effort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ANF 1
#define pos(i, j) (((1 + (i)) * (i)) / 2 + (j))

int *table_red;
typedef struct _mono
{
    int w;
    char **v;
} mono;

typedef struct _poli
{
    int nvars;
    mono **p;
} poli;

void
destroy_mono(mono *m)
{
    if (m == NULL)
        return;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 * m->w ; i++)
        free(m->v[i]);
    free(m->v);
    free(m);
}

void
destroy_poli(poli *p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ((p->nvars + 1) * p->nvars) / 2 ; i++)
        destroy_mono(p->p[i]);
    free(p->p);
    free(p);
}

mono *
new_mono(int w, int idx)
{
    mono *r;

    r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    if (r == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    r->w = w;
    r->v = malloc(2 * w * sizeof(*r->v));
    if (r->v == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 * w ; i++)
    {
        r->v[i] = malloc(4096);
        if (r->v[i] == NULL)
            exit(-1);
        r->v[i][0] = 0;
    }

    return r;
}

poli *
new_poli(int nvars, int w)
{
    poli *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if (p == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    p->nvars = nvars++;
    p->p = malloc(((nvars + 1) * nvars * sizeof(*p->p)) / 2);
    if (p->p == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    nvars -= 1;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nvars ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++)
            p->p[pos(i, j)] = new_mono(w, i);
    }
   return p;
}

void
create_table(int w)
{
    table_red = malloc(2 * w * sizeof(*table_red));
    if (table_red == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 * w ; i++)
        table_red[i] = mod((1 << i), w);
}

int **
read_input(int *npols, int *nvars, int *w, int **enc)
{
    int i, j;
    int **coefs;
    int nv;
    int np;

    *npols = 1;
    *nvars = 1;
    nv = *nvars + 1;
    np = *npols;

    enc[0] = malloc(sizeof(**enc) * np);
    if (enc[0] == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    for (i = 0 ; i < np ; i++)
        enc[0][i] = 0;

    coefs = malloc(sizeof(*coefs) * np);
    if (coefs == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    for (i = 0 ; i < np ; i++)
    {
        coefs[i] =  malloc(((nv + 1) * nv) / 2 * sizeof(**coefs));
        if (coefs[i] == NULL)
            exit(-1);
        for (j = 0 ; j < ((nv + 1) * nv) / 2 ; j++)
            coefs[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return coefs;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int nvars;
    int npols;
    int i;
    int w;
    int *enc;
    int **coefs;
    int k;
    poli **p;

    w = 2;
    coefs = read_input(&npols, &nvars, &w, &enc);;

    create_table(w);
    npols = 1;
    p = malloc(npols * sizeof(*p));
    for (k = 0 ; k < npols ; k++) {
        p[k] = new_poli(nvars, w);
    }
    for (k = 0 ; k < npols ; k++)
        destroy_poli(p[k]);
    free(p);

    for (i = 0 ; i < npols ; i++)
        free(coefs[i]);
    free(coefs);
    free(enc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Juan, I posted the answer because despite the mess in your code, you did write a very good program. It was very unsafe though, you should always check for errors.